# ASP.NET MVC 4 navigation to and back between Views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, navigation

I have two pages: Page1 and Page2 and ASP.net MVC 4. Page1 has a link to Page 2 with some Query string parameters. When clicked on that link we land on Page2 which has a input text box and a "save and continue" button. when clicked on "save and continue" button I will save the value in the text box into database. if saving is succeeded then I need to go back to Page1. If saving fails I need to go back to Page2 itself and reload the page2 with same query string parameters.
How do I achieve this functionality of "save and continue" so that I can properly get to the previous page(Page1) or Current page(Page2). Please ignore about the saving part. my doubt is about navigation between pages preserving the state of those pages. I can add more detail if need here. Please let me know.?
I am thinking I can use `Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString` and `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` but not sure how exactly. Any help is appreciated. Please remind that when we go back from Page2 to Page2 itself in case of failure case as said above, the Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString would change its value.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Page2_SaveAndContinue(FormCollection formCollection, string returnUrl)
            {
                if (SavedToDB)
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrlToPage1);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Redirect(formCollection);
                }
            }
```

Comment: A code sample exhibiting the issue would be great. Ideally allowing to reproduce the problem you are describing.

Comment: Edited my question to include my controller action method. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: How you tried RedirectToAction instead of Redirect. You pass the controller name the action method and the object containing your parameters.